# How do I authenticate externally?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

It seems like the documentation is quite outdated when working with external authentications. Does anyone have an example or documentation that shows how to authenticate externally?

I tried checking the `Web.Core` project, but I am completely lost.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you say it's outdated?

Comment: did you read the docs? https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/User-Management#external-authentication

Comment: @aaron it may not be outdated, but as I read the `Web.Core` project, everything seemed much more complex than only using a single class. That is why I was looking for examples. I couldn't make it work at all.

Comment: @AlperEbicoglu yes, indeed. I read the whole documentation and tried multiple times. Reading `Web.Core` project made me even more confused. I will keep trying until I am able to formulate a better question. Apparently there are no examples available out there.

Comment: at least write the exact problem, show the logs, show what you did, is there any exception etc... otherwise nobody can help you.